# How to give string type data in condition in SQL query in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this below query:

```
sql = "Select FirstName, LastName, Age, Relationship FROM MembersTable WHERE (Age > 21) AND (Relationship != "Me")";
```

"Me" is string type, but how to give string type in SQL query in c#?

Comment: With single quotes `'Me'`

Comment: Naah, not working....

Answer (score 0):

Quote the string with single quote.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either single quotes:

```
Relationship != 'Me'
```

or you could escape the double quotes:

```
Relationship != \"Me\"
```

Comment: At run time it is giving a strange error,  Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression'(Age >21)' AND (Relationship != "Me")'

Comment: Did you try to run the statement in sql management studio (I assume you use sql server. Otherwise you should run the sql statement in the corresponding environment) and you get any error? How do you access your database? Do you use ADO.NET or an ORM?

Comment: See, I am not that much comfortable with C# but I am using OleDb for database